# FindFaces then separate into list

Tags: image-processing, image

I have used `FindFaces` on a list of pictures which contain a number of people. These faces have then been highlighted using `HighlightImage`. What I would now like is a list of cropped images of just the faces (ie. a list of what is in the red squares). How do I go about doing this?

[image]

I have tried

```
ImageTrim[images[[#]],Partition[Flatten@FindFaces[images[[#]]], 2]] & /@ Table[k, {k, 1, Dimensions[images][[1]], 1}]
```

however this resulted in a list of 3 images cropped to fit all of the faces into one photo, as below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
images = Import /@ 
   {"http://www.mountainviewlife.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/group.jpg",
    "http://thechaosroom.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/GroupPhoto_000008314113Medium1.jpg", 
    "http://www.yjevents.com/ny/images/group.jpg"}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Function[{im}, ImageTrim[im, #] & /@ FindFaces[im]] /@ images
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]